# Angular push data into function not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm new with AngularJS and i would like push data for my view here is my code :

```
$scope.cards = [];

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {     
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("users_location");
    var geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
    var posOptions = {timeout: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: false};

    $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
        $scope.cards = [];
        var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
          center: [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude],
          radius: 10.5
        });
        var onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
            firebase.database().ref('users/'+key).on('value', function(snapshot) {
                $scope.cards.push({
                    id: key,
                    image: 'img/adam.jpg',
                    about: "Test message"
                  });
            });
        });
        console.log($scope.cards); // <--- show "[]"

    });
});
```

Why the `console.log($scope.cards);` show me "[]" and if i put this code into the firebase function i have the data ?

Thank you

Comment: Because the firebase callback execute when the data is received. Asynchronous request so $scope.cards is still empty when you console.log it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `console.log($scope.cards);` runs before `$scope.cards` loaded with data.

Add `console.log($scope.cards);` with in angular js `$scope.$watch` to view the data.

If you want to run any code after `$scope.cards` loaded with data, add that code within `$scope.$watch`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the asynchronous behavior of functions and due to that

```
console.log($scope.cards);
```

calll before the result of

`firebase.database()`